# NPE at sun.nio.ch.Util.free(Util.java:199)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, nio

We are using a third party application which uses sun.nio package. We are facing following error very frequently,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.nio.ch.Util.free(Util.java:199)
    at sun.nio.ch.Util.offerFirstTemporaryDirectBuffer(Util.java:176)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:334)
```

This does not stop until the servers are restarted. Overall memory consumption remains at 30%.

I tried searching for this and sun.nio package but could not get any pointers to it. What I am looking for followings

1. Any articles, documentations regarding sun.nio package
2. Source code would be a great help.
3. If you guys have any hint of what "might be" happening in this case, please share the same.

Comment: I got this link http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-sun/nio/sun.nio.ch.htm but Util.java does not show free() function. Seems old version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is decompiled source of Util available:

http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=141860&c=8070720